# Howto automatically remove older package versions from a custom repository?

Tags: localrepository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete old packages from local repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110646/delete-old-packages-from-local-repository)

I want to create a private repository for Ubuntu.
I executed the command `dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz` and successfully created my repository. After a few days, I updated my ubuntu and put the downloaded archives from /var/cache/apt to my personal repository. Again I executed the above command to update my repository, but it shown some issues with versions (multiple versions for same program). I tried with `-m` switch to allow multiple versions, and it was successfully created the repository.

My questions is, can I automatically remove the older versions from my personal Ubuntu repository (It could save my disk space)

Comment: I saw an almost same question in http://askubuntu.com/questions/110646/delete-old-packages-from-local-repository. But The answer is not looking good for me

Comment: Nobody is answering!!!

Comment: Than maybe no one knows an answer. Instead of writing comments like yours, you should try to edit your original question to include more information of what you tried and what the problem is. Also please have a look at these links, as they might be relevant to your problem: http://askubuntu.com/q/170348/17789 , http://askubuntu.com/questions/9809/is-it-possible-to-mirror-the-apt-repositories , http://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly I would recommend that you use [apt-mirror](http://apt-mirror.sourceforge.net/)

This can mirror whole Ubuntu distributions or just ppa's if you want.

It keeps the repo up to date, so you do not have to worry about keeping the versions up to date manually.

You basically just need to run one command every time to update.