# Ubuntu gets freezed, and it is slow

Tags: gnome

First of all, sorry about my english.
I installed ubuntu like, 5 months ago, but now my ubuntu gets freezed and stuck, it waits too way long to load an application,  I had to run another OS to do somenthing that I could perfectly do in Ubuntu. Do you guys know, how to "clean" my ubuntu? I mean, to make it faster? like it used to be at the beginning
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to "clean" your Ubuntu by simply running a command or program, but here are some things you can do that might help:

1) Uninstall packages that you don't need anymore, especially if they run as services.  You can [list packages that are installed](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/) by typing `dpkg --get-selections` at a terminal.  Then uninstall those which you don't need anymore by typing `sudo apt-get remove --purge [package_to_remove]`.

2) Look for programs that are sucking up CPU and RAM.  There are many different ways to do this.  I prefer to type `top` at a terminal.  Consider replacing/removing any programs that are resource hungry.

3) [Switch to a lighter DE such as LXDE](http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/).  You can install this by typing `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You could try running `sudo apt-get clean` or `sudo apt-get autoclean`. You could also try upgrading if you are a couple versions behind. I'd probably do a fresh install, otherwise you can use `sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade`.

[See this askubuntu question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110646/delete-old-packages-from-local-repository)
[This has a guide for a 'safe' upgrade that might be better.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer)

Comment: The `apt-get clean/autoclean` will only delete the downloaded packages.  Nothing is uninstalled, and the packages are re-downloaded the next time a `apt-get update` is done

Answer (score 0):

Check the CPU cooling and graphics card cooling. Most of the times lots of dust and lint get into the cooling fins and fans raising the temperature, hence the low system performance.